# How can you make a div take the height of the shortest child?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a type of mosaic gallery of images but I want it to be able to handle any type of image size*.  I'll define each row to have n images which will all take equal width.

*All original images sizes will be at least the width of parent div width divided by n

For example I have a row of 3 images so each image will take up 33% of the parent div.  The height of these images wont be defined to maintain the aspect ratio but I want the parent div to take the height of the shortest child, not the tallest, to avoid whitespace below shorter images.  I'm not worried about odd cropping here since clicking on the images will actually link off to the full sized images.

```
<div>
   <img style="width:33%">
   <img style="width:33%">
   <img style="width:33%">
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wf338/

In that example I'd like the height of the wrapper div to take the height of the middle w3Schools image cutting off the bottom part of the other 2 images.  Then as the browser width is changed, no matter how narrow, the width will continue to be 33% and the height will change automatically to maintain aspect ratio but there will never be space below the images.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%;background:red;overflow:hidden;" id="container">
    <img src="http://numenta.org/images/stackoverflow.png" style="background:yellow;" id="1"/><!--
        --><img src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Rog/w3schools.com_03.png" style="background:green;" id="2"/><!--
        --><img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" style="background:blue;" id="3"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
var heights = [];
heights.push($('#1').height());
heights.push($('#2').height());
heights.push($('#3').height());
var min_height = Math.min.apply(Math,heights); 
    $('#container').height(min_height);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf338/

I don't see solution without jquery if you doesn't know images heights. If you know, u can set height for lowest img, and don't use jquery.